# Set last month ending balance to next month open balance: Power Query M Function

Tags: function, powerbi, powerquery, m

Using a Power Query M function, I am trying to set current month's ending balance to be next month's opening balance.  I have tried various different date functions (i.e. Date.IsInPreviousMonth) but cannot get this to work.

The attached image shows what I am trying to accomplish using Power Query M formula.

[image]

Comment: You may split ending balance into another table, add 1 month, and merge it back using `Table.Join`. However I'm wondering where should the beginning balances of January (10 and 25) come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with M but is quite complex. [Here is a PowerBI Community post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-previous-row-value-based-on-criteria-O/td-p/125813) that gives options.

I would prefer to use DAX's [PREVIOUSMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousmonth-function-dax) function as opposed to M.

Create a new measure along the lines of:

```
Previous Month Balance = 
             CALCULATE(SUM('Fact - Sales'[Cost Price]),
             PREVIOUSMONTH('Dimension - Calendar'[Date]))
```